# Variational autoencoder obtain high likelihood but produce low quality sample?

Tags: self-study, autoencoders, variational-bayes

I'm watching Ian Goodfellow's [introduction](https://youtu.be/AJVyzd0rqdc) to generative models.

When he was introducing variational autoencoders at 22:29, he said:

> Variational autoencoders are good at obtaining high likelihood, but they tend to produce lower quality samples, and in particular, the samples are relatively blurry.

My questions are:

1. What does it mean by obtaining a high likelihood? Does it means that the density model that VAE learnt centres around those training samples? Is this the reason that causes VAE to produce low-quality samples?
2. Why are the generated samples blurry? Is VAE averaging something when it is generating a new sample?
3. When do we want high likelihood and when do we want high-quality samples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. High likelihood meaning $E_{x \in X}[P(x;\theta)]$ is high, where $P(x;\theta)$ is the distribution over images that the VAE specifies. This corresponds to minimizing the KL-divergence between $P(x;\theta)$ and the ground-truth distribution, which is a good thing.
2. The generated samples are blurry because VAE can only produce samples of the form $\mathcal{N}(f(z;\theta), \sigma^2 I)$. However, what people normally visualize as the output of a VAE is in fact just the decoder without the output noise: $f(z;\theta)$, which is the mean of that distribution. Obviously, viewing just the mean of a distribution will give you a blurred view of the actual output, and viewing the sample with added noise will provide something which looks excessively noisy. **The reason for this is that adding independent gaussian noise is not a great model of how images are naturally generated, yet it is assumed implicitly by using MSE reconstruction loss.**
3. You pretty much always want both when training generative models.

Comment: How would you solve the blurriness? For example by changing the loss kind?

Comment: @Nikaido search for "vqvae2" for the state of the art in VAE models.